# Android start two applications from my app

Tags: android

Okay so I have this code and for some reason it only starts the last intent, not the first intent. Any suggestions?

```
private void launchApps(String m)
{
   if (m.equals("Two"))
   {
      Intent a = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("Firstapp");
      startActivity(a);

      Intent b = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("Secondapp");
      startActivity(b);
   }
}
```

But for some reason only intent b starts, never a.

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint before `startActivity(b);`. I bet the moment `A` starts, `B` immediately starts after and replaces `A`.

Comment: There's only one possible application that can be foregrounded at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
private void launchApps(String m)
{
   if (m.equals("Two"))
   {
      Intent a = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
      startActivity(a);

      Intent b = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
      startActivity(b);
   }
}
```

If it doesn't work.

**Try this**

```
Intent a = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("Firstapp");
    startActivity(a);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Intent b = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("Secondapp");
            startActivity(b);
        }
    }, 500);
```

Comment: Well they aren't classes, but two other apps installed on the phone. Like google chrome and google maps.

Comment: @Jayce ok then see my updated code. Hope it helps you.

Comment: That's My Pleasure :)